# How can I mirror a matrix about one of its dimensions?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using Eigen, but since eigen uses basic maths operators this is basically just a maths question. Here is the pseudo-code for what I am after:

```
    [1 2 3]
A = [4 5 6]
    [7 8 9]

            [7 8 9]
A.flipv() = [4 5 6]
            [1 2 3]
```

How could I achieve something like this in Eigen? (I'm using version 3.2)

EDIT: I think what I want to do here is swap the top rows with the bottom rows (some combination of `.topRows()`, `.bottomRows()` and `.swap()`?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a general flip, i.e., not only for a 3x3 matrix, then the `reverse()` function is what you're looking for. In particular `A.colwise().reverse()` will reverse each column thus doing a vertical flip. For an horizontal flip: `A.rowwise().reverse()`.

Comment: How can I flip the contents using this method? I tried `A = A.colwise().reverse().eval` and `A.colwise().reverseInPlace()` but neither work?

Comment: `A = A.colwise().reverse().eval();` does work for me

Comment: sorry my bad I tried to do `A = A->colwise().reverse().eval()` where `A` is a pointer... subtle but fatal.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to multiply with another 3x3 matrix with zeros and ones in the right places. I think you can solve it using pen and paper from there.
I'll give you a hint: there are just 3 ones in the solution.

.. All right:

```
[0 0 1]
[0 1 0]
[1 0 0]
```

Comment: I don't understand how matrix multiplication can be used to flip a matrix. Maybe I should, I don't know, but I don't.

Comment: @ausairman Consider the matrix `T=[0 1 0] [0 0 1] [1 0 0]`. Compute `T*A` as well as `A*T` to get a feeling of how this works.

Comment: I have up-voted your answer, as I had a single solution in my mind before I have read yours. Just for the record, you have not described the matrix when I have read it, your answer was textual back then, but I still understood it, so I do not understand the down-votes.

Answer (score 3):

I can give you two possible solutions:

1.

If you have n rows in your matrix, you can do the following:
For any element in the first n/2 rows, let's suppose it is on the i'th row and j'th column and we index the rows and columns from 0, then you can swap M[i, j] with M[n - 1 - i, j] and the result will be just as described.

2.

The second solution is Johan Lundberg's solution:

Let's consider the matrix of

```
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

I x M results in the matrix you have desired. For example:

```
0 0 1   1 2 3   7 8 9
0 1 0 x 4 5 6 = 4 5 6
1 0 0   7 8 9   1 2 3
```

Comment: The easiest and more general solution is to use the `reverse()` function as described in my answer.